# Auto-sizing the height of a TileList

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

Is there a way to have the TileList component to auto-size to its contents? I have tried setting it 100%, but it seems that won't help. I don't want to hard-code the height because the content will be vary, and I don't want scrollbars to show up. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving this issue:
First I set the values for rowHeight and maxColumn properties. Then I did a little function that fires on the updateComplete event of the TileList to calculate the height of the tileList by doing a rowHeight * number of rows.
That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an event handler when the tilelist changes, calculate the height based on the children then resize the child list based on that value.